# Cabal install ignores a package in build-depends and then requests for it

Tags: ghc, cabal, cabal-install

Using `cabal` I'm trying to install `iserv-proxy`, it's build depends on `libiserv` and I've installed it before. when I issue install command:

```
ghc/utils/iserv-proxy$ cabal install -flibrary -fproxy
```

it fails with:

```
src/Main.hs:53:1: error:
Could not load module `Remote.Message'
It is a member of the hidden package `libiserv-8.6.3'.
Perhaps you need to add `libiserv' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
53 | import Remote.Message
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

as the error says, the `Remote.Message` is an `exposed-module` in `libiserv`, but the `libiserv` exists in the build-depends of `iserv-proxy.cabal` file, as is in the `8.6.3` version of `ghc`:
(only I changed `containers` upper dependency from `0.6` to `0.7` which was making dependency conflict.)

`iserv-proxy.cabal`:

```
.
.
.
Executable iserv-proxy
Default-Language: Haskell2010
Main-Is: Main.hs
Hs-Source-Dirs: src 
Build-Depends: array      >= 0.5 && < 0.6,
               base       >= 4   && < 5,
               binary     >= 0.7 && < 0.9,
               bytestring >= 0.10 && < 0.11,
               containers >= 0.5 && < 0.7,
               deepseq    >= 1.4 && < 1.5,
               directory  >= 1.3 && < 1.4,
               network    >= 2.6,
               filepath   >= 1.4 && < 1.5,
               ghci       == 8.6.*,
               libiserv   == 8.6.*
```

cabal is aware of `libiserv` installation:

```
$ cabal list --installed libiserv
* libiserv
    Default available version: [ Not available from any configured repository ]
    Installed versions: 8.6.3
    License:  BSD-3-Clause
```

and `build-depends`, as it seems in verbose log of install (`-v`), you may find it here in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/S1VtW5Ey).

It's so weired, I'm fairly new to `cabal` and `ghc` so I might messed something up. When I look into `ghc` command in the above [verbose log](https://pastebin.com/S1VtW5Ey):

```
/opt/ghc/bin/ghc --make -no-link -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -static -outputdir dist/build/iserv-proxy/iserv-proxy-tmp -odir dist/build/iserv-proxy/iserv-proxy-tmp -hidir dist/build/iserv-proxy/iserv-proxy-tmp -stubdir dist/build/iserv-proxy/iserv-proxy-tmp -i -idist/build/iserv-proxy/iserv-proxy-tmp -isrc -idist/build/iserv-proxy/autogen -idist/build/global-autogen -Idist/build/iserv-proxy/autogen -Idist/build/global-autogen -Idist/build/iserv-proxy/iserv-proxy-tmp -optP-include -optPdist/build/iserv-proxy/autogen/cabal_macros.h -hide-all-packages -Wmissing-home-modules -package-db dist/package.conf.inplace -package-id array-0.5.3.0 -package-id base-4.12.0.0 -package-id binary-0.8.6.0 -package-id bytestring-0.10.8.2 -package-id containers-0.6.0.1 -package-id deepseq-1.4.4.0 -package-id directory-1.3.3.0 -package-id filepath-1.4.2.1 -package-id ghci-8.6.3 -package-id libiserv-8.6.3 -package-id network-2.8.0.0-AkCJm1aNSYz7ekXKYyI0pF -XHaskell2010 src/Main.hs
```

It miss any `-I` or `-include` to `libiserv` library, and interestingly `libiserv` installation doesn't have any `.h` file or `include` directory:

```
$ ls /root/.cabal/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.6.3/libiserv-8.6.3-EjLBkFaay9bH1Xm2bkeUPB/
GHCi  Lib.dyn_hi  Lib.hi  Remote  libHSlibiserv-8.6.3-EjLBkFaay9bH1Xm2bkeUPB.a
```

my config:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 2.4.1.0
compiled using version 2.4.1.0 of the Cabal library 
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.3
ghc$ git log -1
Author: Ben Gamari <ben@smart-cactus.org>
Date:   Thu Dec 6 16:58:34 2018 -0500

    Release 8.6.3
```

My `ghc-pkg check` returns couple of warnings for `haddock-html` and `haddock-interfaces` documents missing. you may find full output here in an another  [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6LwPQyVX)

## Update:

adding `--ghc-options="-i../../libraries/libiserv/src/"` to the install command solved my case, but it should not be like that, so I let this question open, looking for better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `libiserv` can be built *with* support for network, and without. By default it will build without. You need `libiserv` to be built with `-fnetwork` for it to expose `Remote.Message`.

Thus you probably want something like:

```
libiserv $ cabal install -fnetwork
iserv-proxy $ cabal install -flibrary -fproxy
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
Ok I see , first I missed the `-fnetwork` flag, and then I reinstalled the `libiserv` with `-fnetwork` which led to create another package containing `Remote` directory inside it (see `/root/.cabal/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.6.3/libiserv-8.6.3-EjLBkFaay9bH1Xm2bkeUPB` above) however then I `unregister`ed and removed first installation. It might messed things up.

Comment: running above commands, `libiserv` reinstalls successfully, but `iserv-proxy` fails to install like before.

Comment: Ok, it seems that first install without `-fnetwork` made something wrong with `ghc` database, when I did `ghc-pkg unregister libiserv` for all of `ghc-pkg list libiserv` occurance and remove all `libiserv` files in user and global directory, then your commands worked successfully. Thanks in advance.